# JQuery animating more elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation

I'm trying to set up an application and I need to animate several items at one time.

```
function getData() {
    for(i=0, i<data.length, i++) {
       ...
       animate(ID, top, left);
   }
}

function animate (ID, top, left) {
    $("#" + ID).animate({top: top, left: left}, {duration: 1000, queue: false});
}
```

What this does is, that it gets data from server through AJAX, gets ID, top and left position. I have divs with these IDs and I need to animate them to position given in left and top coordinates. Problem is, that when I call that function all elements jump to given position except the last one, which animates as it should. Where could be an issue?

Comment: Can you setup a sample demo project in [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net), because I [can't reproduce the problem](https://jsfiddle.net/63khb9n5/1/).

Comment: @ViktorBahtev StackOverflow allows [snipplets](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/). No need for JsFiddle anymore.

Comment: I tried to setup jsfiddle, but there it works okay.. I have it online, on http://unturned.linhy.cz 

All cursors should simulteanously animate to their new positions, but only one animates.

Comment: Okay, I guess, that I found the problem - https://jsfiddle.net/rbxgcycp/

Comment: Why you're adding elements with the same Id? Just remove this line `document.getElementById("positionFrameWrap").innerHTML = document.getElementById("positionFrameWrap").innerHTML + '<div class="div" id="' + i + '"></div>';` and your code will work fine - [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/rbxgcycp/1/)

Comment: That wasn't correct.. I every element has its own ID (varaible ID). In my opinion it was caused because of adding elements and refreshing the div (?) and skipping the animation. I solved it another way, but thanks :D

Answer (score 0):

You can use JQuery multiselection:

```
$("#element0, #element1").fadeIn()
```

In your case:

```
function getData() {
    var ids = ""
    for(i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
       // retrieve 'id', top and left
       ids += "#" + id
       if (i < data.length - 1) {
          ids += ","
       }
    }
    animate(ids, top, left);
}

function animate (ids, top, left) {
    $(ids).animate({top: top, left: left}, {duration: 1000, queue: false});
}
```

This animate all your element, selected by 'id', simultaneously.

Comment: Try changing **$("#element0#element1").fadeIn()** to **$("#element0, #element1").fadeIn();**. In this case, is necessary to separate every id with commas, by this way, the multiselection must work properly.

Comment: @DannyFardyJhonstonBermúdez thanks, I missed commas!